# Page not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I have a situations where I am recieving an observable in witch I have several properties including an observable array.

I need to group that observable array to be able to display them 5 iems at a time with parents of section tag.

This is my html:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: groupedQuestions">
    <section>
        <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
        <article>
            <!-- ko if: hasGrade-->
            <header data-bind="text: description"></header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">9</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">10</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: hasMemo-->
            <header data-bind="text: memoTitle"></header>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </article>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </section>
</div>
```

This is the code I am using to group the observableArray:

```
function categoryIdChanged(category) {       
        vm.category(category);
        vm.groupedQuestions = ko.computed(function () {
            var groups = [];
            var index = 0;
            var group;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(category.questions(), function (item) {
                if (index % 5 === 0) {
                    group = [];
                    groups.push(group);
                }
                group.push(item);
                index++;
            });
            return groups;
        });
    }
```

This is the category model:

```
    categories: [{
    categoryId: 1,
    title: "Docent",
    hasMemo: true,
    memoIsMandatory: false,
    memoTitle: "Docent Opmerkingen",
    questions: [{
        questionId: 11,
        description: "De docent is goed voorbereid",
        hasGrade: false,
        hasMemo: true,
        showOnlyMemo: true,
        memoTitle: "De docent is goed voorbereid"
    }, {
        questionId: 12,
        description: "De docent heeft kennis van zaken",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent heeft kennis van zaken"
    }, {
        questionId: 13,
        description: "De docent kan de onderwerpen boeiend uitleggen",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent kan de onderwerpen boeiend uitleggen"
    }, {
        questionId: 14,
        description: "De docent gaat goed in op de vragen uit de groep",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent gaat goed in op de vragen uit de groep"
    }, {
        questionId: 15,
        description: "De docent stimuleert de groep tot actieve deelname",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent stimuleert de groep tot actieve deelname"
    }, {
        questionId: 16,
        description: "De docent voegt inhoudelijk iets toe aan het studiemateriaal",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent voegt inhoudelijk iets toe aan het studiemateriaal"
    }, {
        questionId: 17,
        description: "De docent is praktijkgericht",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "De docent is praktijkgericht"
    }, {
        questionId: 18,
        description: "Totaal oordeel over de docent",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "Totaal oordeel over de docent"
    }]
}, {
    categoryId: 7,
    title: "Opbouw programma en studiemateriaal",
    hasMemo: true,
    memoIsMandatory: false,
    memoTitle: "Opbouw programma en studiemateriaal Opmerkingen",
    questions: [{
        questionId: 54,
        description: "Het studieprogramma is duidelijk opgebouwd",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "Het studieprogramma is duidelijk opgebouwd"
    }, {
        questionId: 55,
        description: "Het studiemateriaal is compleet, goed leesbaar en praktijkgericht",
        hasGrade: true,
        hasMemo: false,
        showOnlyMemo: false,
        memoTitle: "Het studiemateriaal is compleet, goed leesbaar en praktijkgericht"
    }]
}],
```

The ideea is that my page will contain several links.Each link will corespond to one category.And after each link is clicked a list of questions get displayed.My problem is that my list of pages do not get updated when I click the link.This did not happen before I created the computed value so I figure it must be something related to that.

DOes anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Make a fiddle and give more explanation about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `categoryIdChanged` you are redefining your `groupedQuestions` each time when the method is called.

You only need to define your `groupedQuestions` once and inside your computed you can reference your `vm.category` and then Kncokout will automatically update your `groupedQuestions` when your  `vm.category` changes in the `categoryIdChanged` function.

So you will need to restructure your code to something like this:

```
 function categoryIdChanged(category) {
     vm.category(category);
 }

 vm.groupedQuestions = ko.computed(function () {
     var groups = [];
     var index = 0;
     var group;
     if (!vm.category()) // no category is selected return empty groups
         return groups;
     ko.utils.arrayForEach(vm.category().questions(), function (item) {
         if (index % 5 === 0) {
             group = [];
             groups.push(group);
         }
         group.push(item);
         index++;
     });
     return groups;
 });
```